# Quadratic Objective with Quadratic Constraints in R: Rsolnp?

Tags: r, optimization

I am trying to minimize a quadratic objective with quadratic constraints, is Rolnp the way to go?  I have been reading the documentation and it seems like all the examples use equations instead of vector manipulation.  All of my parameters are vectors and matrices and they can be quite large.  Here is my problem:

```
X<-([Cf]+[H])%*%[A]
Y<-([Cf]+[H]-[R])%*%[B]
```

I want to find H that minimizes `Y%*%Dmat%*%t(Y)` for a given value of `X%*%Dmat%*%t(X)`

Cf, R, A, Dmat and B are matrices of constants.

The values for H sohould be between 0 and 1.

Is it possible to use Rsolnp to find the vector H even though the input functions will all return other vectors?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using AUGLAG and COBYLA to solve this problem.